# Multiplying list elements in HTML based on class from input element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of items with a `<li>` tag and a specific class:

```
<li class="multiply">2 cars</li>
```

I'd like to have an input field where the visitor is able to type a number and all elements with the "multiply" class would be multiplied, as such:

```
<input type="number">5</input>
```

Would change the `<li>` value to:

```
<li class="multiply">10 cars</li>
```

I assume there is a possibility to do this but all my searches have run dry.

Comment: `<li class: "multiply">` isn't valid HTML. Do you mean `<li class="multiply">`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is as below, with some modification of your HTML:

```
<li class="multiply"><span data-original="2">2</span> cars</li>
```

This modification wraps the number to adjust with a `<span>` in order that it can be more easily targeted without relying on regular expressions, or needing to know where the number is located within the string. Further, those `<span>` elements have a custom `data-*` attribute and value which reflects the starting number, and we operate on that number (otherwise there's the risk of an exponential increase in the numbers.

That said, the JavaScript is:

```
// a named function defined using Arrow syntax (since we don't
// need to access 'this'; we pass in the Event Object ('e')
// automagically from the later use of EventTarget.addEventListener():
const multiply = (e) => {

  // e.target is the <input> element, and here we store the value:
  let n = e.target.value,

  // here we retrieve the <span> elements that are the children
  // of the .multiply elements:
    elems = document.querySelectorAll('.multiply > span');

  // using NodeList.prototype.forEach() to iterate over the
  // NodeList of <span> elements:
  elems.forEach(
    // 'el' is the current Node of the NodeList over which we're
    // iterating:
    (el) => {
      // here we set the textContent of the current <span> element
      // to be equal to the result of the input-value multiplied
      // by the value held in the <span> element's data-original
      // attribute-value:
      el.textContent = n * el.dataset.original;
    });
};

// we use document.querySelector() to retrieve the first - if any -
// <input> element in the document (there's no sanity/safety check
// here, in production you should probably guard against the element
// being absent as if it's not there the function returns null).
// We then use EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the multiply()
// function (note the deliberate lack of parentheses) as the event-
// handler for the 'input' event:
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', multiply);
```

```js
const multiply = (e) => {
  let n = e.target.value,
    elems = document.querySelectorAll('.multiply > span');

  elems.forEach(
    (el) => {
      el.textContent = n * el.dataset.original;
    });
};

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', multiply);
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="multiply"><span data-original="2">2</span> cars</li>
  <li class="multiply"><span data-original="66">66</span> chocolate bars</li>
  <li class="multiply"><span data-original="2">2</span> apples</li>
</ol>
<label><input type="number" inputmode="numeric" min="0" max="100" step="1" /> Enter a multiplier</label>
```

References:

- [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.dataset` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
- [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).

Comment: Well, as Rob said under my solution the data could be randomly present (could be even on the end) inside the list item... so this solution would be probably better as the numeric value is wrapped inside a separated elem.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen that comment until you referenced it here, just now. But while the position doesn't necessarily matter for a method such as `String.prototype.match(...)` it's more work than is ideal if the number can be reliably targeted within a specific element.

Comment: I am unable to make this work **yet** as I'm generating the whole `<li>` element, with no solution to add the `<span>` right away. This has, however, helped a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some kind of framework (eg. Angular, React) or templating language for the HTML? Because in plain HTML the `<li class: "multiply">` should be instead `<li class="multiply">`.

There are multiple ways for this to work and each of them requires Javascript. You need to register an event on the input field: `<input type="number" onchange="handleInputChange(this)" value="5" />`.

Then in between a `<script type="text/javascript"> ... </script>` tags you'll need to process the change and rerender the HTML.

Not going to details too much, but here is a working solution for that:
https://codepen.io/whirlion/pen/RwWPRyV

Comment: Updated CodePen to only multiply list items that are using the "multiply" class name.

Comment: I'm using Jekyll to populate a list that will look, roughly, like this one: https://codepen.io/robcsaszar/pen/yLYNaym a number will (99% of times, as I might sometimes have text in there, as well) be present first, followed by a space, and then the item in question.